# How to add a new method in Smalltalk source code?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I am new to Smalltalk and I am trying to add a new method in the `Integer` class present in Smalltalk. The method should go in the 'accessor' protocol. I am using VisualWorks and not finding any option to do that. I have gone through the developers guide still its not clear to me. Can someone please give me screen shots or step wise solution about how to proceed with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open your browser window [Small Talk Launcher --> System --> Browser]
2. Select a Package
3. Select a Class
4. Select a Protocol to which you want to add your new method.

You can find the tab "source" below the 4 partitions [Package, Class, Protocol, Method].
Replace the text in that "source" tab with the source code of your method.

Go to to "edit" option in the Browser menu. 
Select "Accept" option.

Your new method is added successfully!

Cheers!
Aditya.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into Smalltalk idea, you'll de that classes are objects as well and that you can just say class to compile a new method e.i. add a new method to itself:

```
Integer compile: 'getSomeVar ^someVar' classified: 'someVar'
```

_This will add to *Integer* in `someVar` protocol a method called `getSomeVar` that will return `someVar`instance variable._

But for a general workflow you should use tools provided by Smalltalk environment such as a System Browser mentioned by Aditya Kappagantula